# "Operation System Not Found" on Dell N7110

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, dell, bios, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 onto an old Dell N7110 laptop, flashed with the latest A13 BIOS. This laptop is from around 2010/2011 so it has a BIOS, not UEFI. There are no options in the BIOS to change Secure Mode, CSM, UEFI or any other such things as suggested in other answers.

Using the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator, the 22.04 USB itself will not even boot. It just says "Operation System Not Found" (not a typo). However, if I use the Startup Disk Creator to make a 20.04 or earlier installer, they all boot fine.

Using Rufus and selecting "UEFI or BIOS" along with "Add fixes for old BIOSes" I am able to create a 22.04 USB which boots on the laptop, so I'm getting a step further than with Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator. I can complete the installation process this way.

However, after a seemingly successful installation, I reboot and again get the "Operation System Not Found" error. Just to be sure, I'm pressing F12 and manually selecting the correct boot device, the internal SSD.

**Clearly Rufus is doing something to make the installer work on my non-UEFI laptop** and this is great. But whatever it's doing does not seem to get carried over to the actual installation.

So, this is my question. How to get Ubuntu 22.04 running on a non-UEFI Dell N7110 which is able to run 20.04 and seemingly every other version prior to this.

I've also tried installing 22.10 and 23.04 just in case this was a problem introduced in 22.04 which was then fixed, but the newer versions do not seem to work either.

Comment: I would recommend to manually partition your hdd with Gparted if you booted Ubuntu successfully, select your drive in Gparted and create a new partition layout with mbr and trigger installation again, you also should look in the output of the installer maybe ubuntu tries to install grub in efi mode